# How to make an efficient SimplyConnectedQ (check for abscence of holes)?

Tags: regions, geometry, topology

I would like to find an efficient way to detect whether a region has a hole regardless of how many it has. This question ([Separate boundaries of multiply connected region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102538/86543)) shows some methods but it relies on discretizing the region. One can also maybe convert the graphics to an image and use `ImageMeasurements[#, "ContourHierarchy"]&` but it also relies on discretization.

One algebraic geometry way is to use `CylindricalDecomposition` as  in this question : [Connectivity of semi-algebraic set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183349/86543). However that might be too complicated for complex geometries I am not sure.

A naive way would be to consider the center of the region and rotate an infinite line along a discrete set of angles but that might not work with small holes and might require computing a lot of intersections.

Is there an efficient or simple way to check if a region is simply connected ?

Examples:

```
Disk[]

Annulus[]
```

From documentation:

```
Polygon[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {2.5, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 
 1}}, {1, 2, 3} -> {{4, 5, 6, 7}}]
```

[image]

From documentation on cylindrical decomposition under neat examples:

```
disk[{x0_, y0_}, r_] := (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 < r^2

 disk[{-7/4, 9/4}, 1/3] || 
    disk[{9/4, 9/4}, 
  1/3] || (disk[{0, 0}, 5] && ! disk[{2, 2}, 1] && ! 
    disk[{-2, 2}, 1] && (! disk[{0, -1}, Sqrt[5]] || disk[{0, 1}, 3]))
```

[image]

For polygons one can do:

```
RegionEqual[OuterPolygon[poly], poly]
```

**EDIT :**

```
Length@RegionBoundary[poly][[1]] > 1
```

works too

**EDIT :**

```
Length@RegionBoundary[Annulus[]][[2]] > 1
```

Works for an annulus (notice the 2 instead of one as it is a boolean region)

Maybe there is a way to use `RegionBoundary` without checking what it looks like.